# Could I code something in html that could get html code from a link and then run that code?

Tags: html

I want to code something to fetch and run the code using a predetermined link, which will likely by a GitHub raw code link. Would it be possible to code this in html?

To be entirely honest, I mainly code in scratch using turbowarp. I'm trying to broaden my horizons but I don't know much about coding and this is the start.

Comment: If 'the code' is a javascript file hosted somewhere, then yes. You can just use a `<script>` tag pointing to that URL and your browser will then run that code. You may not be able to do it with a Github raw code endpoint, because it won't have the neccerary headers. You _can_ do this with github pages however.

Comment: You keep saying "run the code", but that phrase doesn't so much apply to HTML.  If there is back-end code, you can't access that.  All you can get is the HTML, which is really a document description more than code to run.

Answer (score 1):

You can not code this in html because you don't code in html, you design html (it's a tagong language not a coding lqnguage).

Anyway, to do this, if yoy want to get a full page in to your page you can use iframe. But if you need to get some custom html without refreshing the page ajax (using in javascript) would be best option